# Running .jar file with custom file

Tags: java

I have simple springboot web app, the app contains `service.properties`. This file contains keys and passwords for a service, and obviously they are not present in git.

My flow is following:

1. Push changes to git
2. Run TeamCity build to upload artifact to nexus ( spring-boot-maven-plugin is used to generate fat jar )
3. Have nolio process that pulls `.jar` file from nexus to my VM and executes deployment script.

The problem is the pulled jar contains `service.properties` but the passwords and keys are empty.

So in my deployment script i need to add ( update ) this file to jar, and then run it.

So far i have been using something like

```
jar uf myApp.jar service.properties
java -jar myApp.jar .../Main -arguments
```

However, the current VM i am required to use does not have `jar` command installed ( it does have `java` ) and it will take some time to install it there ( corporate processes... ).

Is there any different way how to add the file to jar ? Is there any trick with classpath or something?

Thanks for help!

Comment: A .jar file is actually a zip file with some Java-specific entries in it.  You probably can safely use `zip -u` to update it.

Comment: @VGR `zip` is also not installed on VM

Comment: Use environment variables or something else for the credentials?

Comment: @Kayaman afaik the company polici FORBIDS this for some reason ( i will need to ask actually ), i can install the `JAR` or/and `zip` command but it will take few days before it gets all the approvals. Thus i was curious if there are some other ways.

Comment: There are plenty of ways, but if all is "forbidden by company policy" maybe you should ask your company what they want/allow. You're wasting our time with this question.

Answer (score 0):

springboot has build-in env variables support for properties, so you can do:

```
app.user=${APP_USER}
app.pass=${APP_PASS}
```

this allows you to set values per environment on the host where you want to run your application

here are some other ways, how to do it:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html